# Both VMware and VirtualBox have guest tools. Are there problems with installing both?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, interference

VMware and VirtualBox both have tools to make a guest interoperate more smoothly with the host.

Are there any foreseeable problems with creating and setting up a virtual machine in VMware, installing VMware Tools, and then opening it up in VirtualBox and adding the tools VirtualBox wants to install?

Comment: Keep in mind, that much of the vm client tools packages are drivers for virtual devices that are presented by whichever VM environment. Do not expect them to be compatible. So I'd give your chances of success about the same as pulling a hard disk out of one physical box, and putting it in a different box with different hardware. I may work, if the system boots at all on the second rig, but even if it does, you will be left with a bunch of cruft to clean up.

Comment: Thank you; would you restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind, that much of the vm client tools packages are drivers for virtual devices that are presented by whichever VM environment. Do not expect them to be compatible. So I'd give your chances of success about the same as pulling a hard disk out of one physical box, and putting it in a different box with different hardware. I may work, if the system boots at all on the second rig, but even if it does, you will be left with a bunch of cruft to clean up. – Frank Thomas Nov 8 '17 at 20:56